# SharePoint 2013 Calendar Event Display

Tags: calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I'm trying to come up with a solution to an aesthetic problem I'm having with Calendar entries, and I am hoping there is one.  Currently if I have a single event in a day, it displays in two rows, one above the other. This is what I want. However, I was wondering if there was a way to switch which is on top and which is on bottom. For example, my entries list the time of the events first, then underneath they list the title. I'm looking to have the title be the first thing the user sees.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you,
Chris

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not possible OOTB

Comment: SharePoint Calendar UI is designed in such a user friendly way that if you have more than 1 event on single day and long titles and user wants to see which events are at which time, then placing time after long titles (which actually are displayed half considering width of the boxes) is not a good idea. That's why time is placed before the Title.